App not getting removed from start up items after uninstallation
App not getting removed from start up items after uninstallation
const key = new WinReg({
hive: WinReg.HKCU,
key: '\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
});
  const appName = 'airtel_reflect';  // Replace with your app name
  
  key.remove(appName, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Failed to remove startup entry: ${err.message}`);
      debugLogs.error(`Failed to remove startup entry: ${err.message}`);
    } else {
      console.log('Startup entry removed.');
      debugLogs.info('Startup entry removed.');
    }
  });


const regDeleteCommand = REG DELETE "HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run" /V "${appName}" /F; exec(regDeleteCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => { if (error) { console.error(Error removing startup entry: ${stderr}); } else { console.log(Startup entry removed: ${stdout}); } });
